# Prove that an orthogonal, monic polynomial does not have a repeated root.

Tags: polynomials

## Context:

Let $\left\{\hat{p}_n\left(x\right)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of orthogonal monic polynomials with respect to the inner product
$$\left(f,g\right):=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx$$

## Question:

Prove that the degree $n$ polynomial $\hat{p}_n\left(x\right)$ does not have a repeated root. (i.e. that it has distinct roots $x_{i}$).

## Attempt

> Here I attempted to prove this by contraction:

Lets assume that $\hat{p}_n\left(x\right)$ **does** have a repeated root.
Ifso then we can represent it as follows:

$$\hat{p}_n\left(x\right)=\left(x-x^{*}\right)^{2}q\left(x\right)$$

where $q(x)$ has degree $n-2$ which implies that $q(x)$ is orthogonal to $\hat{p}_n\left(x\right)$.

Thus:
$$\left(\hat{p}_n,q\right)=0$$
$$\left(\left(x-x^{*}\right)^{2}q\left(x\right),q\left(x\right)\right)=0$$

If I could show that $\left(\left(x-x^{*}\right)^{2}q\left(x\right),q\left(x\right)\right)>0$ then I could achieve the contradiction.

> I know from the properties of this inner product that $(q(x),q(x))>0$. I am unable to untangle the $\left(x-x^{*}\right)^{2}$ from $(q(x),q(x))$ though!

## Question

How can I achieve this contradiction?

How can I show that $\left(\left(x-x^{*}\right)^{2}q\left(x\right),q\left(x\right)\right)>0$ ?

hints appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $(x-x^*)^2$?

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}(x-x^*)^2p(x)^2dx$ is $\ge 0$ and in fact $>0$ !!

Comment: @JeanMarie oh haha, yes the squares! I notice them now!  Thanks.